# Check duplicates between columns of a row

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to loop through a dataframe to check if there are any duplicates within the columns of a particular row and then the result should return the entire row. The column I'm interested in ascends from Prod_code_1 to Prod_code_47. Part of my problem is how to format the column name while comparing if the value in one column for that row matches the adjacent column for that row.

If there are any duplicates within the columns of a particular row then the result should return the entire row/True.

The columns I'm after look something like this (The dataframe has a bunch of other columns not just the ones shown below):

```
Prod_code_1  | Prod_desc_1 | Prod_code_2 | Prod_desc_2 | 
DIS          | DIS         | DIS         | DIS         |  (returns true)
DIS          | DIS         | DIS         | UVA         |  (returns false)
```

And my code:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    for i in range(1,len(df)):
        if df['Prod_code_'+str(i)][row] == df['Prod_code_'+str(i+1)][row]:
             print(row)
```

Error I'm getting is:

> the truth of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any(), a.all()

I know this should be a relatively straight forward operation but I'm stuck and wondering if anyone knows an easy solution to my query. Would greatly appreciate any help. Thank you :).

Comment: have a look at `DataFrame.duplicated()`

Comment: Or at `Series.unique()`

Comment: Brackets are not balanced in `df['Prod_code_'+str(i)[row] == df['Prod_code_'+str(i+1)[row]`. Please show real code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that your requirement is as follows:

- You want to filter out some columns of interest from a big dataframe
- Then you want to check if all columns are equal then a **True** boolean should be returned

If my understanding is correct, then please follow the below solution.

1. **Step 1:**

   - To get your subset dataframe, it seems that your column names are following a pattern, we can use it in a loop and create a new dataframe out of it (There can be a better way but I believe this should work just fine)

     ```
     df_subset = pd.DataFrame() # Creating a new dataframe
     for cols in list(df.columns): # Assuming df is the original dataframe
        if 'Prod_' in cols:
           df_subset[cols] = df[cols]
     ```

     This should return you the subset of columns of interest.
2. **Step 2:**

   - I had a similar work requirement but I had some `np.nan` values within my dataframe which had to be ignored but not removed while performing the check. If this is the case with you then please see below code other wise please skip to the next step:

     ```
        for cols in list(df_subset.columns):
            df_subset.loc[df_subset[cols].isnull(),cols] = df_subset['Prod_code_1']
     ```

     Here I am just replacing the `null` values in any column on any row with the value of the first column (assuming the first column will always hold a value).
3. **Step 3:**

   - Checking if all the column values for a row are equal or not

     ```
        df_is_equal = df_subset.eq(df_subset.iloc[:,0],axis=0).all(1)
     ```

     Here I am just checking the value of the dataframe columns with the value of the first column. Please follow pandas **[eq](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html)** documentation to know more.

These steps should do what you are trying there.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comprehensive answer. I realise the wording of my question and code included was misleading but you understood my problem correctly.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [is_unique](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.is_unique.html#pandas.Series.is_unique) attribute to check if the row only the same value.

```
df.apply(lambda row: row.is_unique, axis=1)
```

Also see:
[Series.nunique](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.nunique.html#pandas.Series.nunique)
[Series.unique](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html#pandas.Series.unique)

Comment: Unfortunately, `is_unique` returns False even for first row. But `nunique` works...

Comment: Thank you but the operation needs to be performed between rows of different columns not on one row

Answer (score 0):

Your data is wide: there are a bunch of fields that track similar metrics. You may find it helpful to melt your df using `df.melt()`.

let's say your dataframe is `df` and you're interested in the fields `list = ['prod_code_1', 'prod_code_2', ... , 'prod_code_47']`

```
meltdf = df.melt(id_vars='some id', value_vars=list, var_name='prod_code')
```

now all your 'prod_code_#' fields are in one column. Hopefully this gets you started in the right direction.